# Understanding the Web Part Zone ID

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, branding

I was wondering when I insert a web part zone into a page layout, it sets the zone ID with a long ID something like ...

g_43F9D5595771428399C207E33FDC92DC

Is there a reason for this or should I give it my own meaningful ID?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in designer? I presume so, **the only stipulation is zoneIDs are unique**, and that is all Designer is doing. I always make mine unique and meaningful, topZone, middleZone etc.

(If it is designer please add designer and year 2010, 2013 etc to your tags)

Comment: What if you got the same ID in another page layout? Is the id only referencing to that specific page layout? 
If you got a page that have 3 different zones and then change the page layout to another one with the same zone id's, do they get "matched" so the web parts will go into the same ID?

Comment: Different layouts can have the same IDs so you can of course base off the same templates for instance